# Creating a UIView Programatically in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Tags: ios, uiview

I want to programatically create UIViews which depend on the size of the bounds of `self.view`. I've put the code to create the UIViews in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

The problem is that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called multiple times when my viewController appears on screen, thus creating multiple instances of the UIView. 
I'm thinking that this could be solved by using some sort of flag.

Is there a better way to do this? Should the code be put somewhere else in the view controller lifecycle?

Answer (score 5):

You should not put creating `UIView` code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you should create it in `viewDidLoad` instead. You can put view frame update code in `viewDidLayout`. Or you can use autolayout so you don't need any view update code manually. I prefer autolayout.

Comment: I have to do it in code since I create a variable number of `UIView`s in my view controller. Also, if I created them in `viewDidLoad` and updated the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, would that not mean that I would have to have each individual `UIView` as a property?

Comment: You could also create your subviews in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. But if you create them in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, you will trigger another layout pass. Also, since a property can be an array or a dictionary, you don't have to have a separate property for every subview. What properties you need really depends on what the subviews are for and how you lay them out.

Answer (score 0):

In the method of viewDidLayoutSubviews, you can get the updated the frame size for UIControls, after that you can programatically create UIViews in the viewDidAppear.

While I do not think you should create UIViews in viewDidLoad method, in autolayout you can not get correct size of views until viewDidLayoutSubviews has been called.